# Buscar dados de tabelas relacionadas

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Sei que para retornar os valores de uma entidade diretamente relacionada no banco se faz assim com LINQ:

```
List<Usuario> lista = banco.Usuario.Include("Tipo").ToList();
```

Mas como fazer para que me retorne os dados de outra tabela relacionada à tabela "Tipo"?
Por exemplo, a tabela "Tipo" tem um relacionamento com a tabela "Situacao" ao qual a tabela "Usuario" desconhece.

Resumindo o relacionamento está assim: "Usuario" com "Tipo" e "Tipo" com "Situacao". Preciso dos dados de "Situacao" vindo junto também.

**DbContext**

```
public partial class BancoDeHorasEntities : DbContext
{
    public BancoDeHorasEntities()
        : base("name=BancoDeHorasEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuario { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tipo> Tipo { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Situacao> Situacao { get; set; }
    public DbSet<sysdiagrams> sysdiagrams { get; set; }
}
```

**Usuario.cs**

```
public partial class Usuario
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdPessoa { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdTipo { get; set; }

    public virtual Tipo Tipo { get; set; }
}
```

**Tipo.cs**

```
 public partial class Tipo
 {
    public Tipo()
    {
        this.Usuarios = new HashSet<Usuario>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdSituacao { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public virtual Situacao Situacao { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
}
```

**Situacao.cs**

```
public partial class Situacao
{
    public Situacao()
    {
        this.Tipos = new HashSet<Tipo>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tipo> Tipo { get; set; }
}
```

**Modelagem do Banco de Dados**

[image: Modelagem do banco de dados]

Em suma o problema é: como obter, também, os dados da tabela "Situacao" quando se busca "Usuario".

Comment: Por que seu `OnModelCreating` dispara uma `UnintentionalCodeFirstException`?

Comment: Na verdade não sei. O projeto foi criado por outro e quando comecei a usar ela estava assim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode adicionar outros *include* à sua expressão *LINQ*

```
List<Usuario> lista = banco.Usuario
                           .Include("Tipo")
                           .Include("NomeTabela")
                           .ToList();
```

**Edit**

Após ver as suas entidades:

Usando LINQ:

```
List<Usuario> lista = banco.Usuario.Include(u => u.Tipo.Situacao).ToList;
```

Usando string:

```
List<Usuario> lista = banco.Usuario.Include("Tipo.Situacao").ToList;
```

[Outros exemplos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#eagerLevels)

Comment: Só que no caso da sua resposta, só servirá para tabelas que estão relacionadas diretamente com "Usuario". E não é o meu caso.

Comment: Preciso dos dados da tabela "Situacao" que está relacionada com "Tipo" que está relacionada com "Usuario".

Comment: Ainda assim não foi. Dá erro de compilação. A entidade Usuario é do tipo `DbSet<>` e não `IQueryable<>`, deve ser isso.

Comment: Achei uma solução aqui. Vou postar. Obrigado @ramaral

Comment: Poste também o seu *DbContext*.

Comment: Já agora poste as classes Usuario, Tipo e Situacao.Para que a minha solução não dê erro julgo que elas têm de ter *navigation property* que definam essas relações.

Comment: Essa solução não envolve o meu problema, pois preciso dos dados da tabela que está em um 2º nível de relacionamento com a tabela "Usuário", que, no meu caso é, a tabela "Situação".

Comment: Você fez algum teste?

Comment: Vou postar a imagem da modelagem do banco, creio que vai ficar mais claro para você.

Comment: Julgo que será assim: `List<Usuario> lista = banco.Usuario.Include(u => u.Tipo.Situacao).ToList;`

Comment: Conforme a documentação você está correto quanto ao uso do `Include` da classe `DbExtensions`. Porém nos deparamos com um `Include` herdado de `DbQuery<TResult>` no meu caso, e sua resposta um `Include` da classe `DbExtensions`. Por isso não compila.

Comment: Sim eu reparei nisso hoje quando voltei a analisar a minha resposta, no entanto o `Include` do DbQuery<TResult> deveria compilar também. Veja [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#eagerLevels)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25152/discussion-between-luidne-and-ramaral).